# Getting file name with prefix and suffix

Tags: java, javascript, regex

I want to write a regular expression that matches file names that start with `zv` and end with `.csv` like:

```
zvabc.csv
zv232323.csv
zvfdsfsdf.csv
```

What regex pattern can identify all above file names?

Comment: why you added java and javascript tags? Which language are you running?

Comment: You can definitely avoid regex here. Use string methods.

Comment: if you are running java then it would be `"^zv.*\\.csv$"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with the following pattern:

```
^zv.*\.csv$
```